# Declare a constant class field

Tags: string, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm supposed to declare a class field for a federal tax rate, which is a constant, with a value .07. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You don't need to say it twice to emphasize.

Comment: What language? What have you tried so far?

Comment: sorry guys it's my first time in here the script suppose to be in java loop

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify a language, I'll throw in a Java solution

```
public class YourClass {
    public static final double TAX_RATE = 0.07;
}
```

In Java naming convention, you name your constants with all upper casing and use `_` to separate words instead of the normal camel casing.

the `final` keyword, is to make it, well, *final* - meaning unchangeable

Anything not withing a block like a constructor or a method is considered a field.

Comment: sorry guys it's my first time in  here the script suppose to be in java  loop